# Is it possible to use a completely custom made HTML email template for Registration Confirmation email on Zoom?

Tags: zoom.us

Recently, my client started using Zoom for their official meeting and he wants me to create a completely custom made HTML email which he will be able to upload on Zoom and send to others whenever necessary.

Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the Zoom account. I'm looked on internet for a documentation to follow. I have got no useful information so far. But I'm beginning to assume that it may not be possible to use a completely custom made HTML email template on Zoom.

Could anybody who has experience with Zoom give me some information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on whether your client is on the Business plan or just a standalone account.

If it is on the Business plan, Zoom [provides some information on how to customize meeting invitations](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/213735683) as part of the admin account:

> 1. Sign in to the Zoom web portal.
> 2. In the navigation menu, click **Advanced** then **Branding**.
> 3. Click the **Emails** tab.
> 4. Next to **Meeting Schedule Email**, click **Edit**.
>    You will see two tab for the separate emails templates:
>
>    - **Plain Text tab**: The email template that is used when you scheduled a meeting using the desktop client, mobile app, and most add-ins/extensions (except for the Outlook add-in and plugin).
>    - **HTML Format tab**: The email template that is used when you schedule a meeting using the Outlook add-in (desktop or web app). See the list of supported HTML and CSS.
> 5. Use custom email variables in the template.
> 6. Click **Preview** to see how the template will appear to users.
> 7. Click **Apply Changes** to save the template.

Unfortunately, if your client is only on the Pro account, such a feature is not available as Branding is [not part of the license](https://zoom.us/pricing).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It will help me a lot. Stay safe.